# Confirmation about selection of radio Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I check if the radio button is checked or not by calling inline function of javascript?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test this</title>
<script>
var cnfrm= function(){
var x=document.getElementById('rdio2').value;
if (x==null || x=="")
    {
       confirm('are you sure?');
       // return false;
      // redirect to where you want
    }

   }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method=post action=index.html>
<br><input type=radio name=rdio id=rdio2 value=b>
<br><input type=radio name=rdio id=rdio2 value=c>
<br>
<input type=submit value=Submit onclick=cnfrm()>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Right now I am not getting anything and it ignore `cnfrm` function, So I want it to execute so that I can check weather it is selected or not.

Comment: Your HTML markup is not valid, IDs must be unique on document context

Comment: @A.Wolff—the IDs are redundant anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `.checked` instead of `.value`.

```
  if(document.getElementById('rdio2').checked==true) {
    return true;
  } else if(document.getElementById('rdio3').checked==true) {
    return true;
  } else if(document.getElementById('rdio4').checked==true) {
    return true;
  }  else {
    return confirm('are you sure?');
  }
```

[`FIDDLE DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/t2wQ7/)

Comment: its not working if i select bottom radio button then it not work properly